# Drop-down dependency using Django and Python

Tags: django, drop-down-menu, dependencies

im still new in using django and python.. I am working on a drop-down dependency in HWname and HWType. I tried many codes but they didn't worked.. Here are my codes. Please help me :)

What I want to happen is for example in HWType I have Flexi and Flexi2, then in HWName I have Female and Male .. If I choose Flexi in HWType, only "Female" will be display in my HWName and If I choose Flexi2, HWName will display "Male" ..

***Models.Py (Codes)***

```
class HWName(models.Model):
    hwnid = models.AutoField(max_length=6, primary_key=True, db_column='id')
    hwnname = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='name')

    class Meta:
        db_table=u'hw_name'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode((self.hwnname))


class HWType(models.Model):
    hwtid = models.AutoField(max_length=6, primary_key=True, db_column='id')
    hwtname = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='name')

    class Meta:
        db_table=u'hw_type'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode((self.hwtname))
```

#### SCBT Inventory(advance search)

```
class Inventory (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(max_length=6, primary_key=True, db_column='id')
    hwname = models.ForeignKey(HWName, db_column='hw_name', default=1)
    hwtype = models.ForeignKey(HWType, db_column='hw_type', default=1)

    class Meta:
        db_table=u'inventory'
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return unicode((self.assetnumber, self.serialnumber, self.hwname, self.hwtype))
```

#### Advanced Search Hardware Form

```
class AdvancedSearchForm (ModelForm):
    hwname = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=HWName.objects.all(), label="Hardware Name")
    hwtype = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=HWType.objects.all(), label="Hardware Type")

    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        exclude = ('id', 'assetnumber', 'serialnumber', 'remarks')
```

***Views.Py (Codes)***

```
def inventory (request):

    ##advanced search form:##
    form = AdvancedSearchForm(request.POST or None)

        ##check if form is not empty##  
    hwname = request.GET.get('hwname', 0)
    hwtype = request.GET.get('hwtype',0)

    if hwname == 'None':
        hwname = ''
    if hwtype == 'None':
        hwtype = ''
```

---

Comment: I don't know if you copied it wrong here, but give some attention to the indentation rules of python

Comment: @J.Ghyllebert :) Thank you for reminding me. There I already fixed the indentation of the codes. Hope you can help me.. I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

try **"django-smart-selects"**
that looks like what you need
https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects